# Selenium unable to locate the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I keep getting the error that says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/input"}
```

I am working on this website, https://new.igashop.com.au/. What I am trying to do is to extract the city I want from the google sheet and type it into the search bar so that I can access the website for that particular city. I cannot find what is wrong with my code. Could anyone give me any advice? Thanks

```
driver = get_webdriver()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://new.igashop.com.au/")
city = product_sheet.col_values(2)[index]
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/input')
search_bar.send_keys(city)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, you do not have problem in getting the city name correctly. If that's working fine, then below code is able to type "city name" inside the search field and then click on it.

**Example cityName**: "Japan"

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "desktop-searchInputBox").send_keys("Japan")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#desktop-searchInputButton svg").click()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The xpath which you are using in your script that is absolute xpath and chances are very high that it get change when you execute script. You should use relative and stable xpath.
One more thing I noticed that when you are opening this website a popup used to open that you will have to close before accessing the input search box.

For search this xpath-

```
//input[@id='desktop-searchInputBox']
```

Answer (score -1):

try copying 'full xpath' and place it instead of xpath

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

To send a *character sequence* to the search field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://new.igashop.com.au/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='close modal'] > span[data-testid='icon-span-testId']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-testid='desktop-searchInputBox']"))).send_keys("Japan" + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://new.igashop.com.au/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='close modal']/span[@data-testid='icon-span-testId']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-testid='desktop-searchInputBox']"))).send_keys("Japan" + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: igashop_Japan]

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to use WebDriverWait method